# Fully visible box shadow through a transparent background

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a hover effect which does the following:

On hover:

1) The element hovers top 4px, left 4px.

2) The background is set to transparent.

3) Text shadow is set to 4px 4px.

4) Box-shadow is set to 4px 4px and is set to the highlight color.

```
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 0 #E56E21;
```

This should give the illusion that just the text moves up 4, 4 pixels, and not the whole element. 
However, even though the background is set to transparent, I can not actually see through the background to just the box-shadow.

The box-shadow should be seen as the new background color to the hovering text but instead I just get an outline around the edges where the element has moved off.

How can I make the background truly transparent?

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WJ83B/3/

Comment: Can you please add the CSS and HTML with the normal and hover state + http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: box-shadow is not rendered under the box (at least in current webkit), so the transparent property works as it should

Comment: Please provide a working JSFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WJ83B/3/

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you should simply put the text into a separate <span> tag and just displace that by using `.yourelement:hover > span`. Then you don't need to fiddle around with the background color stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempted solution is too complicated (and Javascript is overkill for such as simple task). Simply wrap the text in another  tag and displace it, this way your background will stay where it belongs.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ83B/9/)

HTML:

```
<p class="menu_item_brand"><span>something</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_item_brand:hover span{
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```